# Laravel validation failing with valid data

Tags: php, laravel, axios, laravel-5.6

I am sending a valid patch request to update a users profile. I made rules to make a first name and last name required, a birthday is a date a description is spam free and gender is in a list of supplied genders. It fails immediately on the check of first name being there but I check the request and all the information is there. I hope someone can help me to see what I am doing wrong.

Axios patch request

```
axios.patch(
    `/api/users/${this.user.user_name}/profile/edit`, {
    firstName   : this.firstNameEdit,
    lastName    : this.lastNameEdit,
    birthday    : this.birthdayEdit,
    gender      : this.genderEdit,
    hometown    : this.hometownEdit,
    currentCity : this.currentCityEdit,
    description : this.descriptionEdit,
})
```

Laravel rule in request class:

```
public function rules()
{
  return [
     'firstName' => 'required',
     'lastName' => 'required',
     'birthday' => 'date',
     'description' => new SpamFree(),
     'gender' => Rule::in(['male', 'female', 'other'])
  ];
}
```

Exception:

```
The given data was invalid. Status 422.
```

Comment: You can see the full message with more information (which field failed) if you click on the XHR request and go to Preview. Or if you console log your axios response `.catch(err => console.log(err.response.data))`

Comment: Try logging the data you're validating, and the messages that it returns ($validate->messages())

Comment: Axios will send a JSON request so first of all check if it's properly parsed and the data arrives correctly to laravel

Comment: Is validation works without `description` and `gender` ? If yes which gives error?